# Toggle menu by changing styles in Javascript

Tags: javascript, menu, navigation, toggle

I am trying to add a toggle function to a menu.

I'm trying to do this by changing the style of the the menu in Javascript like below.

It seems to work when I click to open the menu but it doesn't work for closing the menu.

```
let toogleNavStatus = false;

let toogleNav = function(){
let getSidebar = document.querySelector(".nav-links");

if (toogleNavStatus === false) {
    getSidebar.style.visibility = "visible";

toogleNavStatus === true;
}

else if (toogleNavStatus === true) {
    getSidebar.style.visibility = "hidden";

toogleNavStatus === false;
}

}
```

Can someone help me figure out what the problem is with this code?

Below is the HTML

```
    <nav class="nav-bar">
  <div class="nav-center">
    <div class="nav-header">
      <a href="index.html" class="nav-logo">
        <img src="./assets/logo.svg" alt="logo" />
      </a>
      <button type="button" class="btn nav-btn">
        <i class="fas fa-bars" onclick="toogleNav()"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-links">
      <a href="index.html" class="nav-link">Home</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-link">All</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contacts</a>
      <div class="nav-link nav-social">
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/">
          <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i
        ></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning a new state for `toogleNavStatus` in your JS.

It should be

```
toogleNavStatus = true;
toogleNavStatus = false;
```

not

```
toogleNavStatus === true; 
toogleNavStatus === false;
```

`=` assigns the value, `==` and `===` compares them.

Comment: Would recommend putting your click event listener on the button instead of the icon in the button.